# Is it required to "build" an Node.js app from its source to use in production environment without babel?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

The question seems to be a newbie, but I didn't find a suitable answer.

When I was using `babel-node` I knew it was required to build my app before using it in production and be capable of use only `node my-app` to run it. I guess it only transpiles the code and nothing more.

But if my app doesn't use `babel-node` and I can run it using `node` in dev. Is it still required to have a build step to deploy to production?

Comment: That depends on what features you're using.  Node supports ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it runs properly when you run it using `$ node` then no, you probably don't need to transpile it.

[Transpilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) in Node are usually used to compile Javascript dialects, i.e [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_TypeScript), [CoffeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript) etc, to Javascript or to allow using ES features that haven't yet landed in a Node version, which is what [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) actually does.

So if you're writing actual ES6 and all the language features you use are supported in your current Node version then there's no need to transpile it.

If this was a browser I would say it's recommended you do so since transpilation steps also do some kind of [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) which is highly recommended so your app loads fast over a network; but since this code lives on a server, then I don't see a need for it.

I'll also note that while I'm familiar with Babel, I don't extensively use it; so don't consider this an exhaustive answer.